# Syntax error while fetching table list from teradata using python

Tags: sql, python-2.7, teradata

For learning purpose, I am trying to fetch table list from Teradata
in Python with the following code:

```
import jaydebeapi
import pandas as pd

try:
   conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
                                      url="jdbc:teradata://10.10.10.10",
                                      driver_args=['@user','@pss'],
                                      jars=['/mnt/TERADATA/tdgssconfig.jar','/mnt/TERADATA/terajdbc4.jar'])

   print("Connection was successful")
except Exception as e:
        print(e)

 #df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Databasename,TableName FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind = \'T\'',conn)
  dfr = pd.DataFrame(df)
  print(dfr.head(3))
```

The above works fine but when I try to fetch the table list based on a Database name then things are not working:

```
 df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Databasename,TableName FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind = \'T\' and DatabaseName ='SALES'',conn)
 dfr = pd.DataFrame(df)
 print(dfr.head(3))
```

getting:

```
Error: Invalid Syntax
```

It has been couple of hours trying to figure it out but not able to get through it. Its very stupid to ask this but please advice where am I going wrong.

```
Ref: https://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1433-To-get-all-the-tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is just a Python syntax thing.  I would expect:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT Databasename, TableName FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind = 'T' and DatabaseName = 'SALES'""", conn)
```

As you have written it, `SALES` is outside the string, no doubt causing a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue. Due to less reputation points I can't mark it as "Correct/Right Answer" but yes this has helped to move forward. 
Thanks a lot!